# MOSFET-N as a switch for several ICs

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, switches, logic-level

I want to use MOSFET-N (MTM232270LBF) as a power switch for several ICs in my project. It should poweron the devices when logic level is high (3.3V) and poweroff when 0V.

I want to ask you if everything is ok with the design presented below.

Especially am I right if the MOSFET-N will work in saturation zone?

Some of the ICs will be connected to uC through SPI, UART, I2C. Everything will be ok when I shutdown the power?

Do I even need R2 resistor or I can connect uC directly?

I want to power the OPAMP for PT1000 temperature signal and the ground will have 0.003V offset from "real" ground. Should I consider this in error calculation for the PT1000 temperature?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2qXJ0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, IRF7413 can not work from 3.3 V. Its max threshold voltage is 3 V. It means it just starts conducting at 2-3 V. The datasheet recommends to drive it by 10 V.

Furthermore, it is a switching MOSFET. Its gate resistor must be small (few Ohms). Most likely, it starts oscillations when driven like this.

And the most important question: do your ICs (I2C TEMP...) have a separate ground from the microcontroller?! The present design breaks GND connection. It is wrong for most cases.

You should use P channel MOSFET with logical level drive for this type of design. It is placed in 3.3 V supply line. The GND wire is common for microcontroller and all devices.

Comment: Informative answer ! And for his other question, 'would it be in Saturtion' Whats your take on it ? Why is it necessary for it to be in saturation ? And for his design we cannot decide wheather it can be in sautration or not because the Drain voltage is not clearly known right ?

Comment: VGS maximum is -20 to +20V. I cant drive it with 3.3V?? As I understand at 1.8V it start to conduct. Datasheet link on the bottom. I suppose 50-100ohm for the uC gate drive will be ok? I will use two measuring devices (with UART communication lines) which producer stated to cut the ground line to properly shutdown. Will it be safe for other ICs (I2C, etc.) to drive microcontroller gpios to ground or tristate them before cutting the ground with mosfet-N? "It is wrong for most cases." - could you elaborate? Thanks! IRF7413 Datasheet: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/107864.pdf

Comment: From datasheet Iv posted: Figure 1 shows driving VGS from 2.5 to 10V. At "Absolute Maximum Ratings" VGS is -+20V and typical threshold is 1.8V

Comment: OK I understand that there is no guaranteed conduction for 3.3V (no table or figure for VGS/RDSon). Iv edited my post and chosed new Mosfet-N: MTM232270LBF. Will this design work?

Comment: What about GND connection? This is the most important problem!!! In your design: you can not connect any signal lines from all ICs (SPI, LEDs...) to microcontroller.

Comment: Before I disconnect the GND I want to put all connected GPIO into high impedance or pull to ground. Is this ok concerning GND connection?

Comment: I have never seen in my life any design that disconnects GND wire for peripheral devices. The common method is to disconnect positive supply. For example, many modern logic ICs are rated for operation with certain positive voltages on their inputs with no positive supply. However, none of them is rated for negative voltage on inputs.

Comment: OK, you can try on your risk. But there are absolutely no benefits in disconnecting GND compared to a switch in positive supply. By the way - pulling IOs to GND in your design would probably kill some chips.

Comment: http://www.atlas-scientific.com/_files/_datasheets/_circuit/pH_EZO_datasheet.pdf
Section "known issues" paragraph 2.

Answer (score 1):

1. No there is no guarantee it will be fully on. Use a MOSFET (P-channel) that has a guaranteed and acceptable Rds(on) at the gate drive you will be using (or less gate drive). You should not be looking at Vgs(th) or typical curves for this purpose. Use Vgs(th) to ensure the MOSFET will be **off** (almost never a problem when the gate is driven by a CMOS output).
2. Breaking the ground connection will usually cause more problems than breaking the Vdd connection, but even if you use a high-side switch you still must make sure that the uC is not causing the protection networks to conduct. Typically you would tristate or drive outputs low before turning the power off to the section you want to cut. I suggest a P-channel MOSFET high-side switch. You can drive it with another N-channel MOSFET or a BJT. You can find N/P-channel duals in SO8 package with all the required characteristics for a solid design guaranteed.
3. R2 limits the current from the uC port pin to the MOSFET gate capacitance, which might otherwise reach several tens of mA depending on the uC. If you take it out the circuit *might* still work if you have large bypass capacitors, but I think it's quite worthwhile. Since you will have, I would hope, bypass capacitors in the 'power optional' section, switching the power rapidly will tend to (briefly) reduce your Vdd temporarily to a voltage related to the ratio of the bypass capacitors on either side of the MOSFET. Naturally, this could reset the microprocessor or cause other problems. Using a large value of gate resistor (even 10K) will slow the power-on ramp and help mitigate the problem by limiting the dv/dt and thus the current to a level that your power supply regulator can handle.

Comment: 1. I need to use Mosfet-N. Can you explain me why Mosfet-N will not be guarantee turned on connected like that? Iv read this source before posting here: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_7.html      3. I change R2 to 100ohm is that alright?

Comment: You can drive the gate with 10V and it will be guaranteed, just as it  says in the datasheet (recommended reading). As I said above, lower R2 may cause interesting problems but it probably won't damage anything.

Comment: Iv read the documentation: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/107864.pdf
Please can you explain me where in this datasheet states it needs 10V? Figure 1 and figure 3 - it is driven VGS from 2.5V. At 3.3V VGS the IDS is >10A. Please explain me why I need VGS 10V???

Comment: There is no guaranteed minimum Rds(on) at 3.3V. It might work or it might not. If that is okay for you, nobody is stopping you.

Comment: OK I understand now. You are right there is no good figure o table for low VGS...